What exactly does 'using artificial intelligence.. not allowed ' or something like that on the math website rules mean?
It is a bit unclear as to what is meant in the math section by using artificial intelligence ... is not allowed. For example does that include using symbolic math tools such as Maple, Maxima and many others? I would not think so but not really sure. Can someone give an example of something or references to online tools or whatever that ARE using artificial intelligence. Do such a websites or 'tools' exist for doing that very thing - that is using artificial intelligence? If so is it free? I am not intending to use it on here or the math section to post answers but I am also curious about it.

ChatGPT is the usual offender.  For whatever reason, people use that to post questions or, more frequently, to post solutions.   If you ask the system to solve a problem, it will generally offer up a word salad.  Relevant words, sure, but not responsive to the question.  here is a good list of examples (on Stack Exchange generally).  And here

To stress:  it's routine to post solutions that use computer algebra systems.  Maple, Wolfram Alpha, Mathematica, MatLab and so on. Nothing wrong with that, though of course the output is subject to the same standards that any other computation would be.

To clarify @lulu's prior remark, it is ok to use software tools while composing your solution, but generally it is not ok to simply copy and paste the output of some software system as your answer, cf. this meta question.

We want to preclude posts composed by "generative AI" software, eg. ChatGPT and its ilk (large language models).  You should post content that you understand well enough to explain to whomever reads your post.  In short you take ownership of what your posts mean.

i want to accept the first below my question with the 6 beside it by@lulu as an accepted answer but i can't seem to do that. OR has noone claimed to answer the question and is that the problem and they are only comments. if so what do the numbers to the far left with only and up arrow mean. i mistakingly pushed on the up arrow and it made the number go higher on the last comment or answer with a 6 beside it and now made it go one higher to 7. can i take that back and if so how. and why is there no down arrow beside the number and only an up arrow –
user158293

As you are finding out, comments and answers are two very different things. In particular, you can accept an answer, but you can't accept a comment (you can encourage a user who has left a comment to post it as an answer, but the user doesn't have to do so). You can upvote or downvote an answer, but comments can only get upvotes, not downvotes. Why? I don't know, but that's how it works.
